# Date format Asp.Net - LINQ Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

```
.Where(x => x.POD_DATE == xDATEx)
```

I need to check if `xDATEx` is the same date as `x.POD_DATE`
but `xDATEx` gives me results like **2011-07-17 00:00:00.000**
and the `x.POD_DATE` gives **2011-07-17 01:15:43.577**

How do I compare them, despite the results not being in a date only format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx

```
using System.Data.Objects;

.Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.POD_DATE) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(xDATEx))
```

Comment: Error 2 The name 'EntityFunctions' does not exist in the current context

Comment: do you know any other way? i cannot fix it

Comment: you need to have the using directive for it at the top of your code file. Using System.Data.Objects;

Comment: dylan, can you please explain more i do not understand you answer:( how can i set a day after and do this:
Where(x=>x.POD_DATE>=xDATEx && x.POD_DATE<=y1DAYAFTERy);

?

Comment: jakub, Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Objects' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you added a reference to System.Data.Entity? Please visit the link to MSDN I've included.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xDate2 = xDATEx.AddDays(1);
var q = new OrderDataRepository()
               .GetAllOrderData()
               .Where(x => x.POD_DATE >= xDATEx && x.POD_DATE < xDate2)
```